# How to upgrade httpd to use current?

Tags: openbsd

I am running OpenBSD 6.8 and would like to upgrade httpd to the -current version to enjoy a new feature.

Is this possible without upgrading the entire operating system?

Comment: Wait a month and upgrade the whole system to 6.9. The issue is not upgrading `httpd` but not upgrading the rest of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. In OpenBSD you cannot mix release/stable with other versions because other versions depend on other parts of the OS, eg. API/ABI. Sometimes developers add/remove/change some internals so an app depending on such internals won't work.

OpenBSD doesn't keep backward compatibility like Linux.

Comment: Well, it's _possible_, but you get a monster system that will be a _real pain_ to maintain later down the line, and nobody will want to help you with sorting out the issues, because "you must have known what you were doing" :-) Also note that once you bring a system from `-release` or `-stable` to `-current`, it's _tricky_ to bring it back to e.g. `-stable` (which is what you want to run your production systems on).  Better to just wait for the next `-stable` to come around.

Comment: Well, *-stable* in OpenBSD doesn't bringe new features at all. It's just release with patches. @Kusalananda probably confused this with FreeBSD. And as I said, in OpenBSD libc is often changed...

Comment: "Just" patches? Some would argue that patching a security hole is the same as adding a feature. But sure, if you want to run your stuff on an unpatched system, I'm not going to argue with you.